# Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError) Function DocumentSnapshot.get() requires between 1 and 2 arguments, but was called with 0 arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get Events from my Firebase database, but I have no idea, why I got this error :

```
Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function DocumentSnapshot.get() requires between 1 and 2 arguments, but was called with 0 arguments.
```

I have used very similar way in other components and everthing was right then...

```
 const getEvents = async () => {
        const ref = await firebase.firestore().collection('uzytkownik').doc(selectedUser);

        firebase.firestore().collection('wydarzenie')
            .where("uczestnicy", "array-contains", ref).get()
            .then(async resp => {
                console.log(resp)
                const new_array = await Promise.all(resp.docs.map(event => {
                    console.log(event)
                    return event.get().then(resp => {
                        let new_event = {
                            ...resp.data(),
                            id: resp.id
                        }
                        return new_event;
                    })
                }))
                console.log(new_array)
                setUserEvents(new_array)
            })
    }
```

resp :
[image]

event :
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling `event.get()` at all.  If you already have the document from the query, there is no need to get it again.

Comment: `resp.docs` is array of references, so `event` is reference

Comment: No, it's not.  The array is of DocumentSnapshot, with actual document contents.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: Program shows one `console.log(event)` and `console.log(resp)`. I added photos to my ask... This `event` object looks like firebase reference for me...

Comment: It's not, though.  `resp` is a QuerySnapshot.  I suggest reading the API documentation for QuerySnapshot - you will see that its `docs` property is an array of QueryDocumentSnapshot, which is essentially the same as a DocumentSnapshot.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Comment: `event.ref.get().then(resp => {` I don't know if this is the best way to solve it, but it works :P

Comment: Because I don't know how to get this data using only `event`, what I think you meant writing `If you already have the document from the query, there is no need to get it again.`

Comment: There's really no point in getting each document again.  The data is all right there in the snapshot you have already.  Just call data() on each `event` to get an object with the field data.  You should look at the query examples in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're looking for this:

```
const ref = await firebase.firestore().collection('uzytkownik').doc(selectedUser);

firebase.firestore().collection('wydarzenie')
    .where("uczestnicy", "array-contains", ref).get()
    .then(async snapshot => {
        const new_array = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                return {
                    ...doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id
                }
            })
        }))
        console.log(new_array)
        setUserEvents(new_array)
    })
```

At the end of this the `console.log(new_array)` will log data and ID of all documents that match the query.